# Outlook 365, error 8000FFFF (unexpected) when retrieving MAPI session

Tags: outlook-addin, mapi

I've been maintaining a legacy C++ project for some years using VS2012, it consists of an add-in to Outlook, and an out-of-process COM server.  The server needs a MAPI session and Outlook's session (`pMarshalledMAPISession`) and the Outlook application (`pMarshalledOutlookApplication`) are marshalled to it.

This bit of code is used to get a MAPI session object that it can use:

```
pMarshalledMAPISession->QueryInterface( IID_IMAPISession, (LPVOID*) &pMAPISession );
```

There is nothing special here, and it has worked with Outlook, 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016.  What is happening with Outlook 365, is that the call to `QueryInterface()` is returning 8000FFFF (unexpected error).  `MAPIInitialize()` has been called.  I've tried getting the session from the Outlook application like this:

```
Outlook::_ApplicationPtr outlookApplication = nullptr;
Outlook::_NameSpacePtr outlookMAPISession = nullptr;
IUnknownPtr lpUnkMAPISession = nullptr;
LPUNKNOWN lpMAPISessionDisp = nullptr;

outlookApplication = pMarshalledOutlookApplication;
outlookApplication->get_Session(&outlookMAPISession);
hr = outlookMAPISession->get_MAPIOBJECT(&lpUnkMAPISession);
hr = lpUnkMAPISession->QueryInterface(IID_IMAPISession, (void**)&lpMAPISessionDisp);
```

Again, this code works with previous versions of Outlook, but the the final call to QueryInterface() fails with error 8000FFFF on Outlook 365.  I've also tried using the currently active Outlook.Application object, but with the same error.

Is there a kind saint who could tell me how to get a MAPI session, usable in the OOP server, from the Outlook application? Please excuse the scrappy, non-homogenous samples, the code is mid-tinker.